# How do I integrate a nodes edit form on a page?

Tags: nodes, forms

I would like to integrate a nodes edit form on a page. For example, I want to alter the node with ID id equal to 1.
I know there are a lot of ways to achieve this, but I can imagine there is only one right way.

I am having some troubles with my form. After certain time, the edit form shows values from different nodes: some from this, some from the other, etc. I really don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean by _node as form_? Do you mean the edit form for of the existing nodes? Or the create node form to create new nodes?

Comment: edit form of existing node can be found at `node/[nid]/edit` after some time you just redirect user to edit form, will this work ?

Comment: I would like to integrate this form into page, so i have to go another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `drupal_get_form(NODETYPE . '_node_form', NODEOBJECT);` as callback in your custom menu item.
The original node module callback for menu item 'node/%node/edit' is located in the node.pages.inc file:

```
/**
 * Menu callback; presents the node editing form.
 */
function node_page_edit($node) {
  $type_name = node_type_get_name($node);
  drupal_set_title(t('<em>Edit @type</em> @title', array('@type' => $type_name, '@title' => $node->title)), PASS_THROUGH);
  return drupal_get_form($node->type . '_node_form', $node);
}
```